# Adding a new cookie in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, cookies, setcookie

I used the following code to set a cookie in ASP.NET Core 6, but no cookie is created with this code in my browser.

```
var options = new CookieOptions()
        {
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2),
            Path = "/"
        };

 Response.Cookies.Append(CookieName, serializer.Serialize(cartItems), options);
```

Please, if anyone knows what the problem is or if there has been a change in .NET 6, I would appreciate it if they could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had used this piece of code in my program class.

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Lax;
});
```

and in pipeline

```
app.UseCookiePolicy();
```

But when I removed these codes, cookies were added

Answer (score 0):

alright, i tested this in asp.net 6 and its working for me. can you try this format?

```
var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions(); 
cookieOptions.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
cookieOptions.Path = "/";
Response.Cookies.Append("SomeCookie", "SomeValue", cookieOptions);
```

Comment: This is more troubleshooting than an answer. All you've really done here is replace `CookieName` and the serialized `cartItems` with "SomeCookie" and "SomeValue". There's no reasoning as to why you think this will work any differently either.